# Views as blocks - dropdown filters

Tags: 7, views, blocks

On Drupal 7 I have a view with filters exposed to the user, which are dropdown lists. I want to use this View as a Block within a page. The only way to get this to work is the tick the "Use AJAX" checkbox in the Advanced section. However this means that the dropdown lists change to autocomplete fields, and I want to keep them as dropdowns. Is there any way to do that?

(Alternatively, is there any way to add the options that appear in the tabs at the bottom of a piece of content to a view page?)

Comment: `However this means that the dropdown lists change to autocomplete fields` Works fine for me, still drop downs. See demo **https://d0wuf.ply.st/node** feel free to login as admin, the block view is at the header. **(link will self destruct in 23 hours)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is also a module Better exposed filters. Gives more options for the user. Maybe it is possible to do it with that module